# Duplicate controller when using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I'm usnig AngularJs 1.2.25. I have a route config:

```
$routeProvider.when(
    '/config-root',
    { 
        templateUrl: configRootTemplate,
        controller: "ClientConfig",
    }
).when(
    '/config-action/:action/:_id',
    { 
        templateUrl: configActionTemplate, 
        controller: "ClientConfigAction",
    }
).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

In the ClientCOnfig controller, I have a $scope.listConfig variable binding with template for creating, updating list of config.

Everything ok when the first time I visit "config-root" route, I can generate, update... the list.

But when the second time or so far, $scope.listConfig change properly when generate list, update... but the template does not change.

I think when I visit that route again, a new instance of $scope created and does not binding with the template.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rootScope to preserve the value for the next time.

change that `$scope` to $rootScope and access that when ever its required.

If you don't want to pollute the $rootScope you can just store the values in a localStorage as a string and fetch it when ever its required.

```
// To store the value 
localStorage['config'] = JSON.stringify(someObj)  
// To fetch the value 
var myConfigObj = JSON.parse(localStorage['config'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think this solution is not my need. Because $rootScope is global, not good for managing variables. If using localStorage, I can not use data binding of angularjs.

Comment: Than you can use constants which you can inject into to any controller. Refer angularjs constants.